# Conflict between group by, case when, and where while using CTE

Tags: mysql, database, common-table-expression

I have a long query, with joins from multiple tables. But for the sake of asking question here, I have simplified the query.

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
    id,
    ( (price * quantity) + ((gst * quantity) + (gst2 * quantity))
    ) gross_revenue 
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY id
),

cte2 AS (
    SELECT 
    id,
    ROUND(gross_revenue, 2) gross_revenue,
    ROUND((gross_revenue), 2) gross_profit
    FROM cte1
),

cte3 AS (
    SELECT id, gross_revenue, 
        CASE 
           WHEN gross_profit < 0
            THEN 0
           ELSE 
            gross_profit
        END gross_profit
    FROM cte2
)
    
SELECT 
    id, gross_revenue, gross_profit
FROM cte3 

WHERE gross_profit >= 22.27 

LIMIT 25
```

The above query gives me the following error:

**Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'cte1.gross_revenue' in 'where clause'**

When I remove either GROUP BY, CASE WHEN
or replace WHERE to HAVING then the the query works correctly
or I remove the condition of gross_profit from WHERE clause,
Or if extract CASE WHEN from cte3 to the final SELECT statement, then the query works fine.

I am confused as what is the technical reason of this behavior?

Why is it working with HAVING but not with WHERE?

Why does it work fine when I extract CASE WHEN to the final SELECT statement?

Why does GROUP BY of cte1 is making problem at the very final SELECT statement?

Why does it work if I remove gross_profit condition from WHERE clause?

**Sample Data for the given columns**

```
id    price,     quantity    gst     gst2 
1    90.0000     1.00        0.0000  0.0000
2    10.0000     1.00        0.0000  0.0000
3    30.0000     1.00        0.0000  0.0000
4    70.0000     100.00      0.0000  0.0000
5    500.0000    1.00        0.0000  0.0000
6    20.9100     20.00       2.0900  0.0000
7    100.0000    1.00        0.0000  0.0000
8    100.0000    -1.00       0.0000  0.0000
9    20.9100     -20.00      2.0000  0.0000
10    9.7100      1.00        0.0000  0.0000
11    80.0000     1.00        0.0000  0.0000
12    1100.0000   1.00        0.0000  0.0000
13    870.0000    1.00        0.0000  0.0000
14    947.0000    1.00        0.0000  0.0000
15    10.0000     1.00        1.0000  0.0000
16    200.0000    1.00        0.0000  0.0000
17    300.0000    1.00        0.0000  0.0000
18    600.0000    1.00        0.0000  0.0000
19    350.0000    1.00        0.0000  0.0000
20    10.0000     1.00        0.8000  0.0000
21    50.0000     1.00        0.0000  0.0000
22    60.0000     1.00        0.0000  0.0000
23    150.0000    1.00        0.0000  0.0000
24    20.0000     1.00        2.0000  0.0000
25    29.9500     1.00        3.0000  0.0000
```

**Edit**
Interestingly for me this query works on mysql-8.0.31 but not on mysql-8.0.27.

Comment: The published query cannot produce the published error. Please add sample data as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have added the sample data

Comment: *this query works on mysql-8.0.31 but not on mysql-8.0.27* Looks like you have a misprint in the query executed on 8.0.27. Test - remove all CTEs except `cte1` and add `SELECT * FROM cte1` as outer query then check for the output structure.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the suggestion. I have removed the aliased columns that were used in CASE WHEN, now the query is working fine. But I still have to find out the technical reason for why the SQL query in question does not work as it is.